# LibGDX IsometricTiledMapRenderer issues

Tags: libgdx, isometric, tiled

I'm having an issue where my isometric map is rotated 90 degrees anti clockwise when rendering with the IsometricTiledMapRenderer.

Image of the issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LukJE.jpg

```
public class Heist extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public static final String MAP_NAME = "map.tmx";

  OrthographicCamera camera;
  IsometricTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
  TiledMap map;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, 30, 20);

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load(MAP_NAME);

        mapRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/32f);
        mapRenderer.setView(camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
    mapRenderer.render();
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's because of this line.

```
camera.setToOrtho(true, 30, 20);
```

The y axis is inverted in this case. We want it to be.

```
camera.setToOrtho(false, 30, 20);
```